# rails active_storage:install fails in app created with --minimal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I made an app with `--minimal` since standard rails apps are bloated and I would rather add pieces one at a time so I don't end up with unused dependencies, etc.

But when I try to add ActiveStorage, I get the following:

```
rails aborted!
Don't know how to build task 'active_storage:install' (See the list of available tasks 
with `rails --tasks`)
```

Same result with `rails active_storage:install:migrations` and `app:active_storage:install:migrations`.

I have uncommented this line in `application.rb`:

```
require "active_storage/engine"
```

But that didn't solve it. I created another app without the `--minimal` flag and it works just fine for that one so I am sure I am just missing some piece of the puzzle.

Any help is appreciated!

NOTE: I am using Windows Subsystem for Linux with an Ubuntu distro. Rails 6.1.4

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails active_storage:install`, just tried reproducing your problem and I got no errors (Raisl 6.1.4).

Comment: Got the same error. I should mention I am using WSL on windows with an Ubuntu distro. I wonder if that could be tripping me up.

Comment: Must have done something wrong because it started working.

Answer (score 0):

Must have done something wrong because it started working. I think the application.rb file didn't get saved.